# Does Flex or Flash have a list of default cursors in the Flex SDK or Flash runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

There appears to be some default cursors that come with either the Flex SDK or Flash or both. Is there a list of cursors that are default.

I'm looking specifically for hand, arrow and text cursors. The reason I ask instead of creating my own is to keep a consistent look and feel.

**Note**:
There is a constant in the CursorManager class for CursorManager.NO_CURSOR.

**Note**:
There is the Flex busy cursor class `mx.skins.halo.BusyCursor`

**Note**:
There is the busyCursorBackground style. 
The documentation on that property states:

> The class to use as the skin for the busy cursor background. The
>   default value is the "cursorStretch" symbol from the Assets.swf file.

I don't see any other cursor classes or assets except for the busyCursor class already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Flex you can let the cursor change to the button cursor automatically by setting the component's buttonMode property to true:

```
myButton.buttonMode = true;
```

If you want to change the cursor programmatically you can do it like that:

```
Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.ARROW;
Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;
Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.HAND;
Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.IBEAM;
Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO;
```